# How can I mock a nested @Composable in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, robolectric, mockk

I'm attempting to run non-instrumented tests using jetpack compose and robolectric. I've had some success in basic testing, for the most part tests work like their instrumented counter parts, but can't figure out how to mock a nested @Composeable function.

```
@Composable
fun ScoreboardTileTeam(
    team: String = "Team Name",
) {
    Text(team)
    Logo() //This is the function I'd like to mock in my tests.
}

@Composable
fun Logo() {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(R.drawable.logo),
        contentDescription = "Logo"
    )
}
```

Being able to see that the nested function was called and what parameters it was called with would fulfill my primary needs.

It seems that mockito and mockk are built around mocking classes by replacing/augmenting the class's sub methods, but with the `@Composable` annotation these functions appear to be stand alone.

Comment: After using mockStatic, to mock the top level function, I'm stuck working around the test using a @Composable function outside the Composable context. After more research this might be a big no-no. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main/docs/do_not_mock.md

Comment: Why not just use an instrumented test?

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this is still relevant, but I made a tool for this recently: https://github.com/jeppeman/mockposable

You can use it like so:

```kotlin
mockkStatic("fqname.of.LogoKt")
everyComposable { Logo() } returns ...
```